# Mailgun, Mandrill and Ses Driver, SMTP and phpmailer, Which one to use in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: smtp, laravel-5, phpmailer, mandrill, mailgun

Laravel documentation discusses different mail packages which we can install through composer and use. I wanted to implement the mail functionality in a site so this question popped up in mind. Which one is the best option in smtp, phpmailer, mandrill and mailgun etc and why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It matters for which kind of e-mail you are sending.

What you should aim is: have the best reputation/cost for your project.
Reputation means deliverability (not being flagged as spam)

If it is transactional like:
Password changes, account updates Mandril is not bad and has excellent deliverability. Be aware that Selling or newsletters are against mandrill TOS.

If you project has more a Seller side in order or reputation:

Mailgun and SendGrid
PHPmailer and local SMTP

Mailgun and Sendgrid permit mail campaigns having that the customers have opted-in for that.

PHPMailer and local SMTP will rely on the reputation of your Server IP. The more times passes by, the more your reputation grows.

All of these options have PHP SDK and libraries and Laravel is a Fantastic FrameWork.